# JHipster Embedded Tomcat Access Logs

Tags: jhipster

I can't get access logs working for embedded Tomcat with JHipster (v8 beta or v7). I got them working for a regular Spring Boot project instantly, so I don't know why I can't get them working when I create an app using JHipster. Although I used application.properties instead of application.yml or application-dev.yml in my plain Spring Boot app.

My application.yml and application-dev.yml files both include this:

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
    org.apache: DEBUG
    org.apache.tomcat: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    site.myapp: DEBUG
    tech.jhipster: DEBUG
    org.apache.catalina: DEBUG

server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      directory: /Users/myuser/mylogdir
      enabled: true
      prefix: access-log
      suffix: .log
      file-date-format: .yyyy-MM-dd
      pattern: common
    basedir: target
```

The log files are never created. Neither in `mylogdir` or `target`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JHipster uses Undertow by default.

Comment: @MattRaible Ohhh, hahaha. That would explain it. I'm marking your comment as the accepted answer. XD Thank you!